# import a module in local env from a docker

Tags: docker

There is a module compiled by the author in the provided docker container. How can I import the module in python in my local system from the docker container? Docker is so new to me. My system is Ubuntu 18.04.
Because there is a lot of data and dependencies in my own system, I don't want to download them again in the docker container.

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? Because some IDE allows you to use docker containers as a remote python interpreter...and this might be your solution another way is to copy the specific dependency from the container to your local machine...but i personnally prefer th first way

Comment: @yAzou But there  may be more dependencies in my local system, if I choose the firt way, I can't not use my own dependencies, right?

Comment: @ravikt The case is that: I want to compile a module named "spconv" in my local system to run a project, but a lot of errors occured, so I choose to docker pull a docker image provided by the "spconv" author. However, I realize that I can not use other dependencies  in my own system I need in the docker image. So, module A is in docker, module B is in my local, how can I use module A and B in local is my question.

Comment: On which OS are you running ?

Comment: @shawn-zhuang In that case you should try building a new docker image. The "spconv" author has provided the Dockerfile. You can add the modules you want to install.

Comment: @yAzou Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @ravikt yes. I think I have to rebuild again all modules in the provided docker. Thanks

Comment: @shawn-zhuang do you need help in preparing Dockerfile?

Comment: @ravikt yes, that would be nice to give me some advice~Thanks.

Comment: @shawn-zhuang in the spconv Docker file, add the package you want to install. For ex: if you want to install numpy, scipy etc, then you need to add `RUN pip3 install numpy scipy`. Once you have added the packages, build the docker image. to day that run `docker build -t <image-name> Dockerfile .`

Comment: @shawn-zhuang you can put the Dockerfile in a separate directory. Once the image is built, you can use it the way you used your older docker image. You new docker image will inherit all the packages form `scrin/dev:latest`